# Webpack vendor bundling

Tags: node.js, npm, webpack, webpack-2

I've created a vendor bundle of all my third party scripts. I'm referencing the new `vendor.bundle.js` into my `index.html` file.

It seems as though none of the third party scripts are actually accessible from my `main.js` file. Any ideas what I'm potentially doing incorrectly?

**webpack.config.js**

```
var CommonsChunkPlugin = require('webpack/lib/optimize/CommonsChunkPlugin');

module.exports = {
    entry: {
        vendor: ['babel-polyfill', 'jquery', 'jquery-match-height'],
        main: './src/main.js'
    },
    output: {
        path: './dist',
        filename: 'bundle.js'
    },
    module: {
        loaders: [
            {
                test: /\.jsx?$/, loader: 'babel', exclude: /node_modules/,
                query: { plugins: ['transform-runtime'], presets: ['es2015'] }
            }
        ]
    },
    plugins: [
        new CommonsChunkPlugin(/* chunkName= */"vendor", /* filename= */"vendor.bundle.js")
    ]
};
```

Comment: Do you get some error in your browser console? Did you check if the file `vendor.bundle.js` is actually created?

Comment: @Ematipico yeah vendor bundle compiles correctly. I'm getting an uncaught reference error.